# Bot state error, but not using Bot State

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I'm getting an exception on the following post with my Bot Framework bot on Azure, but I'm not using Bot Builder Framework to manage State Data. I'm doing that myself in my database.

POST /v3/botstate/skype/conversations/...

There's no reference to userdata or conversationdata anywhere in my code. So why is this post happening and why am I getting this exception and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which post? Which exception?

Comment: All bots use state service for storing the dialog stack.  It does not matter if you aren't using UserData, ConversationData or PrivateConversationData in your code: it is used by the bot builder internally.  So, please add either InMemoryDataStore or use one of the Azure Extensions: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some instances where if you don't explicitly declare where the state is stored it will still use the bot state service.

Have a look at the sample code here:-
https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/26/saving-state-sql-dotnet

If you are already doing this, then please post the exception and share your code.